# Ошибка DB в Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away
```

Ошибка возникает при запуске очереди через демон, сервер баз данных удаленный, не локальный.

Выполнил запрос `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%'`

в строчке стоит  - `wait_timeout  - 28800`

ошибка генерируется постоянно и пишется в логи Laravel.
Хотя при запуске очереди все отрабатывает успешно, но не пойму почему эта ошибка постоянно генерится.

Вот кусок кода с выполняемой задачи

```
class SendNotifications extends Job implements ShouldQueue {

use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

public function handle() {

   $users = $user::where('status', 1)
        ->where('external_id', '!=', 0)
        ->where('subscribe', 1)
        ->get();


    if ($users) {

      foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
            $index = $key + 1;
            $status = ($uc > $index) ? 'next' : 'last';
            $this->dispatch(new SendUsers($user));

        }
      }
   } 
}
```

Внутри Job я выполняю mysql запрос на выборку юзеров, но в логах происходит ошибка чуть ли не каждую секунду

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away`

```
laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(576): PDO->beginTransaction()
```

В конфигурации ---> `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),`

Запуск очереди ---> `queue:work database --queue=getuser --daemon --sleep=3 --tries=3`

Я так понимаю что демон делает опрос базы данных с интервалом и проверяет нет ли задач в базе в табличке jobs и каждый раз при попытке сделать выборку с таблицы получает эту ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

```
->where('external_id', '!=', 0) change to `->where('external_id', '<>', 0)`
```

Comment: И чем это отличается от моей записи??? Я же говорю у меня нет ошибок синтаксиса, только вот эта ошибка  ---- SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away